# sec:authorize dont work in spring security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm trying to use spring security taglib, in 3.2.8.RELEASE version this code works correctly, but with the 4.0.2.RELEASE version does not work,
doesn't render the sec:authorize tag content, and the user has the role SUPER_ADMIN:

```
   <sec:authorize access="hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inptAdmin" >Usuário responsável:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        ...
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </sec:authorize>
```

**My spring configuration:**
spring version: 4.1.7.RELEASE, spring security: 4.0.2.RELEASE

WEB.xml:

```
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<display-name>Expenses Manager</display-name>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.configuration" />
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.service" />


<jee:jndi-lookup id="mysqlDS" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDS" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDS" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />



<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
            </prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">C:/Users/eduardo.santos/Documents/Comerbem/admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations" >
        <list>
            <value>classpath:app.properties</value>         
            <value>classpath:app#{systemProperties['ENV']}.properties</value>           
        </list>         
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <!-- setting maximum upload size 5mb -->
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5242880" />
</bean>
```

spring-security:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<security:debug/>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="false" >
    <security:headers disabled="true"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />

    <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/acesso?error" 
        login-page="/acesso" default-target-url="/" username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password" login-processing-url="/do_login" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/acesso?logout" logout-url="/do_logout" invalidate-session="true" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/acesso*" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"  />


    <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/post/publicar/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBRO')"/> -->


</security:http>

<bean id="exAuthenticationProvider" autowire="byType" class="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.security.ExAutenticationProvider" />


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="exAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

spring-servlet:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" />
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<resources mapping="/login/**" location="/login/" />
<resources mapping="/dist/**" location="/dist/" />
<resources mapping="/bower_components/**" location="/bower_components/" />
<resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
<resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <!-- <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" /> -->
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>



<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.api" />
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.edubarbieri.comerbem.controller" />
```

I could do nothing to solve this problem, can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

My pom.xml

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com</groupId>
<artifactId>edubarbieri</artifactId>
<name>admin</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <spring.versao>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.versao>
    <spring.security.versao>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.versao>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.versao}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.versao}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.versao}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.versao}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
        <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>expenses</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***SOLUTIONS:***

...

In spring security 4, hasRole add by default prefix 'ROLE_' at first:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means specifically.

Comment: Doesn't render the sec:authorize tag content, and the user has the role SUPER_ADMIN.

Comment: Tested on Security 4.0.0 RELEASE with Spring 4.0.0 RELEASE and it's working fine; maybe has to do with the revision you are working with but should be fine.

Comment: Is the role `SUPER_ADMIN` or `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`. the `hasRole` function by default adds the role prefix which is `ROLE_`. If the role is actually `SUPER_ADMIN` use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, it's work for me.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904857/secauthorize-returning-true-for-both-isauthenticated-and-isanonymous-in-thy/40492335#40492335

Answer (score 1):

You need the Spring Security Taglibs in your classpath. For Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to add the taglib to the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"   prefix="sec" %>
```

Comment: Tank you for reply, but i did it.